# Magento 2: Track Order

Tags: magento2, shipping, sales-order, exception

I have followed the below steps to install

1) downloaded from https://marketplace.magento.com/mconnectsolutions-trackorder.html

2) extracted and placed code `app/code/Mconnectsolutions/Trackorder`

3) run the below commands

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 generated pub/media pub/static var/*
> ```

5) getting error in the fronted below is the screenshot of error.

[image: Magento 2 Track order]

Comment: Please check the permission of that new extension's folder and files. Also, check your root/current server user have the permission of that new extension's folder and files.

Comment: @kunj i have checked permissions also but getting same issue

Comment: Have you checkd root user can edit those files?

Comment: So, you got the solution, right?

Comment: Ok, Welcome, Happy to help you!!

Comment: Please accept that answer, so it will help to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your, root user has permission to edit/delete that extension's files AND folder's. If not then allow access root user.